# how to visualize line chart in R using ggplot having date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have following data set and I want to visualize it in Line chart or any thing using `ggplot` in R

```
 Date                    x       y       Total       
2019-06-02               23      45        68
2019-06-03                0      72        72 
2019-06-04               54      10       156
2019-06-05               62      21        83
```

I want to visualize data, x, y columns in line chart using `ggplot` in R.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach with `ggplot2`. You have to reshape your data to long. Also as yu want dates, be sure you have your variable in date format. You only want `x` and `y` so you can add a `filter()` statement to only consider those variables. With data in that format is possible to get a plot as you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% mutate(Date=as.Date(Date,'%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date)) %>%
  filter(name!='Total') %>%
  #Sketch the plot
  ggplot(aes(x=Date,y=value,group=name,color=name))+
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Date = c("02/06/2019", "03/06/2019", "04/06/2019", 
"05/06/2019"), x = c(23L, 0L, 54L, 62L), y = c(45L, 72L, 102L, 
21L), Total = c(68L, 72L, 156L, 83L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Date`.
x do not know how to convert 'Date' to class “Date”
i Input `Date` is `as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")`. I am getting error while exectuing this can you please help me out here

Comment: @priya I have added the data you shared in the answer. First try reproducing the code with that data. I suspect the issue you have is because of format in variable. Let me know how that goes!

Comment: @priya That is weird. Try first replicating the code with `df` I added and loading all required libraries!

Comment: I am able to figure it out , is there any way to make the charts interactive like I want to see the numbers on the chart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221287/discussion-between-priya-and-duck).

Comment: @priya You can use `geom_text()` to add the text in your chart!

Comment: @priya You posted a question recently. I have answered with what you want please check and let me know if that works!